# import a complex .docx file as .xml and extract the chapters

Tags: r, xml, indexing, extract

--update-- maybe someone can assume another possibility so split a `.docx`document into its chapters, importing `.docx`to R

first of all, I want to give thanks for this awesome forum. I found several solutions for my upcoming issues.
But this time I haven't found anything...

However, I have a complex `.docx` document, containing an index, formatted to `.xml`.

```
library(XML)
xmlfile <- xmlParse("C:/Users/Documents/stihl.xml", options = HUGE)

topxml <- xmlRoot(xmlfile)

topxml <- xmlSApply(topxml, function(x) xmlSApply(x, xmlValue))
xml_df <- data.frame(t(topxml), row.names = NULL, node)
```

And other possibilities to read an XML file. 
My `.docx` document has an index and now I want to extract the several index content. As an `.docx` example

```
1. Introduction  
   This is an introduction importing XML by R.  
2. UserGuide  
   Userguides are often helpful.  
2.1 Style  
   The style should be always the same.  
2.2 Language  
   I hope my Language is readable, because I'm contacting you from Germany.
```

As a result it would be nice to receive the content of the seperated chapters, for example stored in a vector.

```
result 
[1]This is an introduction importing XML by R.
[2]Userguides are often helpful.
[3]The style should be always the same.
[4]I hope my Language is readable, because I'm contacting you from Germany.
```

Maybe there are other possibilities keeping the structure but I mentioned an XML import containing the tree structure as the easiest way.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<?mso-application progid="Word.Document"?>
<pkg:package xmlns:pkg="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/xmlPackage">

  <pkg:part 
    pkg:name="/_rels/.rels" 
    pkg:contentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-package.relationships+xml" 
    pkg:padding="512">
    <pkg:xmlData>
       <Relationships xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/relationships">
          <Relationship 
           Id="rId3" 
           Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/extended-properties" 
           Target="docProps/app.xml"/>
          <Relationship 
           Id="rId2" 
           Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/relationships/metadata/core-properties" 
           Target="docProps/core.xml"/>
          <Relationship Id="rId1" 
           Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/officeDocument" 
           Target="word/document.xml"/>
       </Relationships>
    </pkg:xmlData>
  </pkg:part>

  <pkg:part 
   #serveral relationships
  </pkg:part>

  <pkg:part 
    pkg:name="/word/document.xml" 
    pkg:contentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document.main+xml">
     <pkg:xmlData>

      <w:document mc:Ignorable="w14 w15 wp14" 




    xmlns:wpc:http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingCanvas
   xmlns:mc:http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006
   xmlns:o:urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office
    xmlns:r:http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships
    xmlns:m:http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/math
    xmlns:v:urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml
    xmlns:wp14:http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingDrawing
    xmlns:wp:http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/wordprocessingDrawing
    xmlns:w10:urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word
    xmlns:w:http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main
    xmlns:w14:http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordml
   xmlns:w15:http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2012/wordml
    xmlns:wpg:http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingGroup
    xmlns:wpi:http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingInk
    xmlns:wne:http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2006/wordml
   xmlns:wps:http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingShape

         <w:body>

           <w:p> ...
          </w:p>

          <w:p w14:paraId="5BB64FEF" w14:textId="77777777" w:rsidR="005A3789" w:rsidRDefault="005A3789" w:rsidP="005A3789">
           <w:pPr>
            <w:pStyle w:val="Inhaltsverzeichnisberschrift"/>
           </w:pPr>
           <w:r>
            <w:lastRenderedPageBreak/>
            <w:t>Inhaltsverzeichnis</w:t>
           </w:r>
          </w:p>
```

'Inhaltsverzeichnis' is the titel of my index. The path is 
package -> 3.part -> xmldata -> document -> body -> p

The information is stored here for example

```
<w:p w14:paraId="15ECF978" w14:textId="77777777" w:rsidR="009B5500" w:rsidRDefault="005A3789">
<w:pPr>
<w:pStyle w:val="Verzeichnis1"/>
<w:rPr>
<w:rFonts w:eastAsiaTheme="minorEastAsia"/>
<w:b w:val="0"/>
<w:noProof/>
<w:color w:val="auto"/>
<w:lang w:eastAsia="de-DE"/>
</w:rPr>
</w:pPr>
<w:r>
<w:rPr>
<w:b w:val="0"/>
</w:rPr>
<w:fldChar w:fldCharType="begin"/>
</w:r>
<w:r>
<w:instrText xml:space="preserve"> TOC \o "1-4" \h \z \u 
</w:instrText>
</w:r>
<w:r>
<w:rPr>
<w:b w:val="0"/>
</w:rPr>
<w:fldChar w:fldCharType="separate"/>
</w:r>
<w:hyperlink w:anchor="_Toc474825312" w:history="1">
<w:r w:rsidR="009B5500" w:rsidRPr="009D0220"><w:rPr>
<w:rStyle w:val="Hyperlink"/>
<w:noProof/>
</w:rPr>
                  **<w:t>1</w:t>**
</w:r>
<w:r w:rsidR="009B5500"><w:rPr><w:rFonts w:eastAsiaTheme="minorEastAsia"/>
<w:b w:val="0"/>
<w:noProof/>
<w:color w:val="auto"/>
<w:lang w:eastAsia="de-DE"/>
</w:rPr><w:tab/>
</w:r>
<w:r w:rsidR="009B5500" w:rsidRPr="009D0220">
<w:rPr>
<w:rStyle w:val="Hyperlink"/>
<w:noProof/>
</w:rPr>
                  **<w:t>Management Summary</w:t>**
</w:r>
<w:r w:rsidR="009B5500">
<w:rPr>
<w:noProof/>
<w:webHidden/>
</w:rPr>
<w:tab/>
</w:r>
<w:r w:rsidR="009B5500">
<w:rPr>
<w:noProof/>
<w:webHidden/>
</w:rPr><w:fldChar w:fldCharType="begin"/>
</w:r>
<w:r w:rsidR="009B5500">
<w:rPr>
<w:noProof/>
<w:webHidden/>
</w:rPr>
<w:instrText xml:space="preserve"> PAGEREF _Toc474825312 \h </w:instrText>
</w:r>
<w:r w:rsidR="009B5500">
<w:rPr>
<w:noProof/>
<w:webHidden/>
</w:rPr>
</w:r>
<w:r w:rsidR="009B5500">
<w:rPr>
<w:noProof/>
<w:webHidden/>
</w:rPr>
<w:fldChar w:fldCharType="separate"/>
</w:r>
<w:r w:rsidR="009B5500">
<w:rPr>
<w:noProof/>
<w:webHidden/>
</w:rPr>
               **<w:t>6</w:t>**
</w:r>
<w:r w:rsidR="009B5500">
<w:rPr>
<w:noProof/>
<w:webHidden/>
</w:rPr>
<w:fldChar w:fldCharType="end"/>
</w:r>
</w:hyperlink>
</w:p>
```

This is the first entry of the index, **1. Management Summary 6**

Comment: It would help to have a minimal example of the input xml

Comment: I hope it's now better to understand, below this last p package, there are serveral p packages containing the content between <w:t> content </w:t>

Comment: I think it miss the `w` prefix definition. Can you find in the xml something like `w="http://schemas......"`?

Comment: Yeah of course, in the end there are 16 schemas. Sorry  I skipped them ...

Comment: You may want to check out this package, [officer](https://davidgohel.github.io/officer/), it could help you deal with the docx without having to get too dirty with the xml

Answer (score 0):

We can use:

```
library(xml2)
library(magrittr)

x <- read_xml("path/to/file.xml")

titles <- xml_find_all(x, 
               "/pkg:package//pkg:part/pkg:xmlData/w:document/w:body/w:p/w:hyperlink/w:r/w:t") %>%  
         xml_text() %>% 
         matrix(ncol = 3, byrow = T) %>% 
         as.data.frame()

colnames(titles)<- c('numChapter', 'title', 'numPage')
```

This retrives the text inside all the nodes corresponding to that xpath.

Based on your given example that xpath contains (what I suppose are) the `numChapter`, its `title` and its `numPage`.

---

As noted this will give an error if the xml is not well formed and/or some namespaces are missing.

Hope this helps

Comment: Mhh unfortunatelly not really. `part_xml <- xmlSApply(topxml[[3]][[1]][[1]], function(x) xmlSApply(x, xmlValue))
xml_df <- data.frame((part_xml), row.names = NULL)` has the same output. My Problem is, the output has no structure, so the text is not linked or grouped by the chapter titles

Comment: Where in the xml is the result you want 'structured'? I supposed that 'Inhaltsverzeichnis' was the first  node that you are interested in and there are several similar later.

Comment: Wow nice, this worked fine, now I have the índex with numbers extracted! Is there now a possibility to add the content of each chapter as kind of a 4. column ?

Comment: It is surely possible, and even simpler, just `xml_find_all(x, 'xpath/to/chapter/content') %>% html_text()` and then `cbind` to `titles` df.
Pls consider accepting and upvoting the answer if you find it useful

Comment: Mhh, but I think there is one problem: often the content is splitted to some `<w:p>`'s, such as (pseudo):  `<w:p>  <w:t> title chapter 2 </w:t> <w:t> this is the first sentence</w:t> </w:p> <w:p><w:t>and this is the second part</w:t></w:p>`and because of this, I thought there is some refering link ID in the content `<w:p>`'s to refer to its chapter title

Comment: Hard to tell without knowing the exact structure, I think you should open a new question with a complete example, I'll gladly help there

Comment: Thanks a lot @GGamba ! I will open a new question, concerning chapter extraction!