# Extracting structured content from Word XML

Tags: r, xml, xpath, openxml, docx

I want to extract the text content from Word documents while preserving the document structure.  [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42225937/import-a-complex-docx-file-as-xml-and-extract-the-chapters) comes closest and provides the starting point.  [Here is a dummy word document.](https://www.dropbox.com/s/858sl0qqw0jgg9y/example.docx?dl=0) I've unzipped it and included the `document.xml` below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<w:document xmlns:wpc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingCanvas" xmlns:mo="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mac/office/2008/main" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:mv="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:mac:vml" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" xmlns:m="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/math" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:wp14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingDrawing" xmlns:wp="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/wordprocessingDrawing" xmlns:w10="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main" xmlns:w14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordml" xmlns:w15="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2012/wordml" xmlns:wpg="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingGroup" xmlns:wpi="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingInk" xmlns:wne="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2006/wordml" xmlns:wps="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingShape" mc:Ignorable="w14 w15 wp14"><w:body><w:p w14:paraId="09AE8A7D" w14:textId="338F199D" w:rsidR="00D8348A" w:rsidRPr="00987637" w:rsidRDefault="00987637" w:rsidP="00987637"><w:pPr><w:pStyle w:val="Title"/><w:rPr><w:sz w:val="40"/><w:szCs w:val="40"/></w:rPr></w:pPr><w:r w:rsidRPr="00987637"><w:rPr><w:sz w:val="40"/><w:szCs w:val="40"/></w:rPr><w:t xml:space="preserve">The </w:t></w:r><w:r w:rsidR="00A6772E"><w:rPr><w:sz w:val="40"/><w:szCs w:val="40"/></w:rPr><w:t>Example Docx</w:t></w:r><w:bookmarkStart w:id="0" w:name="_GoBack"/><w:bookmarkEnd w:id="0"/></w:p><w:p w14:paraId="0803A50C" w14:textId="77777777" w:rsidR="00987637" w:rsidRDefault="00987637"/><w:p w14:paraId="0EDF635A" w14:textId="77777777" w:rsidR="00987637" w:rsidRDefault="00987637" w:rsidP="00987637"><w:pPr><w:pStyle w:val="Heading2"/></w:pPr><w:r><w:t>Introduction</w:t></w:r></w:p><w:p w14:paraId="2AF32AB2" w14:textId="77777777" w:rsidR="00987637" w:rsidRDefault="00987637"/><w:p w14:paraId="4DB9AE94" w14:textId="6C08452A" w:rsidR="00987637" w:rsidRPr="00987637" w:rsidRDefault="00C52D6C" w:rsidP="00987637"><w:r><w:t>This is the introduction para.</w:t></w:r><w:r w:rsidR="00A6772E" w:rsidRPr="00A6772E"><w:t xml:space="preserve"> </w:t></w:r><w:r w:rsidR="00A6772E"><w:t>Awesome.</w:t></w:r></w:p><w:p w14:paraId="676B3B48" w14:textId="77777777" w:rsidR="00987637" w:rsidRPr="00987637" w:rsidRDefault="00987637" w:rsidP="00987637"/><w:p w14:paraId="17CE18FE" w14:textId="77777777" w:rsidR="00987637" w:rsidRDefault="00987637" w:rsidP="00987637"><w:pPr><w:pStyle w:val="Heading2"/></w:pPr><w:r><w:t>Chapter 1</w:t></w:r></w:p><w:p w14:paraId="58A187F6" w14:textId="77777777" w:rsidR="00987637" w:rsidRDefault="00987637"/><w:p w14:paraId="2815D3B5" w14:textId="58856A78" w:rsidR="00C52D6C" w:rsidRPr="00987637" w:rsidRDefault="00C52D6C" w:rsidP="00C52D6C"><w:r><w:t xml:space="preserve">This is the </w:t></w:r><w:r><w:t xml:space="preserve">chapter 1 intro </w:t></w:r><w:r><w:t>para.</w:t></w:r><w:r><w:t xml:space="preserve"> </w:t></w:r><w:r w:rsidR="00A6772E"><w:t>Awesome.</w:t></w:r></w:p><w:p w14:paraId="7010E2CD" w14:textId="77777777" w:rsidR="00987637" w:rsidRDefault="00987637" w:rsidP="00987637"/><w:p w14:paraId="52D9B766" w14:textId="77777777" w:rsidR="00987637" w:rsidRDefault="00987637" w:rsidP="00987637"><w:pPr><w:pStyle w:val="Heading3"/></w:pPr><w:r><w:t>Chapter 1.1</w:t></w:r></w:p><w:p w14:paraId="055DB7AC" w14:textId="77777777" w:rsidR="00987637" w:rsidRDefault="00987637" w:rsidP="00987637"/><w:p w14:paraId="22A2C473" w14:textId="1D3FE489" w:rsidR="00A6772E" w:rsidRPr="00987637" w:rsidRDefault="00A6772E" w:rsidP="00A6772E"><w:r><w:t xml:space="preserve">This is </w:t></w:r><w:r><w:t>section 1.1</w:t></w:r><w:r><w:t xml:space="preserve"> </w:t></w:r><w:r><w:t>text</w:t></w:r><w:r><w:t>. Awesome.</w:t></w:r></w:p><w:p w14:paraId="1F60E111" w14:textId="77777777" w:rsidR="00987637" w:rsidRDefault="00987637" w:rsidP="00987637"/><w:p w14:paraId="62A6FEE6" w14:textId="77777777" w:rsidR="00987637" w:rsidRDefault="00987637" w:rsidP="00987637"><w:pPr><w:pStyle w:val="Heading3"/></w:pPr><w:r><w:t xml:space="preserve">Chapter </w:t></w:r><w:r><w:t>1.2</w:t></w:r></w:p><w:p w14:paraId="3B8DA076" w14:textId="77777777" w:rsidR="00987637" w:rsidRPr="00987637" w:rsidRDefault="00987637" w:rsidP="00987637"/><w:p w14:paraId="43519FB7" w14:textId="311F726C" w:rsidR="00987637" w:rsidRDefault="00A6772E" w:rsidP="00987637"><w:r><w:t>This is section 1.</w:t></w:r><w:r><w:t>2</w:t></w:r><w:r><w:t xml:space="preserve"> text. Awesome.</w:t></w:r></w:p><w:p w14:paraId="2D6908F2" w14:textId="77777777" w:rsidR="00987637" w:rsidRDefault="00987637" w:rsidP="00987637"/><w:p w14:paraId="3189011C" w14:textId="77777777" w:rsidR="00987637" w:rsidRDefault="00987637" w:rsidP="00987637"><w:pPr><w:pStyle w:val="Heading2"/></w:pPr><w:r><w:t>Chapter 2</w:t></w:r></w:p><w:p w14:paraId="6FFC56CD" w14:textId="77777777" w:rsidR="00987637" w:rsidRDefault="00987637" w:rsidP="00987637"/><w:p w14:paraId="3E9AE930" w14:textId="329881E3" w:rsidR="00987637" w:rsidRPr="00987637" w:rsidRDefault="00A6772E" w:rsidP="00987637"><w:r><w:t xml:space="preserve">This is </w:t></w:r><w:r><w:t>the c</w:t></w:r><w:r><w:t xml:space="preserve">hapter </w:t></w:r><w:r><w:t>2</w:t></w:r><w:r><w:t xml:space="preserve"> </w:t></w:r><w:r><w:t xml:space="preserve">text. </w:t></w:r><w:r><w:t>Awesome.</w:t></w:r></w:p><w:p w14:paraId="57F0B3DF" w14:textId="77777777" w:rsidR="00987637" w:rsidRDefault="00987637"/><w:p w14:paraId="48315F42" w14:textId="77777777" w:rsidR="00987637" w:rsidRDefault="00987637"/><w:sectPr w:rsidR="00987637" w:rsidSect="00751697"><w:pgSz w:w="11900" w:h="16840"/><w:pgMar w:top="1440" w:right="1440" w:bottom="1440" w:left="1440" w:header="720" w:footer="720" w:gutter="0"/><w:cols w:space="720"/><w:docGrid w:linePitch="360"/></w:sectPr></w:body></w:document>
```

This reads in the xml:

```
library(xml2)
library(magrittr)
doc = read_xml('document.xml')
```

I'm unclear about next steps to extract the content from this.  I tried:

```
xml_find_all(doc, "/w:body/w:p/w:hyperlink/w:r/w:t") %>% xml_text()
```

But this returns nothing.  Grateful for assistance.  My goal is to export the text content in some format that preserves the document structure - perhaps a csv with columns reflecting the tree from `Title` through `Heading 1` etc to `Normal`.

----------------------------------------\

Edit:

The example doc structure is as I see it:

```
Title
-- Heading 2
-- -- para
-- -- Chapter 1
-- -- -- para
-- -- -- Chapter 1.1
-- -- -- -- para
-- -- -- Chapter 1.2
-- -- -- -- para
-- -- Chapter 2
-- -- -- para
```

To be honest I'm flexible on output (json is fine) but it needs to reflect this approx doc structure.

Comment: You'll have to be much more specific about what you mean by *some format that preserves the document structure*.  It's in a highly structured format already (OOXML).  Tables/CSV fundamentally don't represent tree structures well.  Perhaps if you state your true end goal we might be better able to help.

Comment: BTW, your XPath cannot possibly succeed if for no other reasons than it neglects the `w:document` root element and references a `w:hyperlink` element when none exist in your document.

Comment: @kjhughes I've hopefully answered your question about document structure and desired output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You're likely severely underestimating the complexity of the task.**

XPath is for selection.  It would be a simple matter to write an XPath expression to extract a set of nodes from your OOXML document.  For example, this XPath 2.0 expression,

```
//w:p[w:pPr/w:pStyle/@w:val='Heading2']/string()
```

will return for your document:

```
Introduction
Chapter 1
Chapter 2
```

**If you want to do more than *select*, if you want to *transform*, then you'll want to step up to XSLT.**  You'll also have to delve into 5K+ pages of OOXML specification to handle everything that can be done in a Word document.  Note that indentation levels, since they can come from styles, can be particularly tricky to cover in general.

XPath is amazingly powerful for *selection*, however.  I'll leave you with one more XPath 2.0 expression,

```
//w:p[normalize-space()]/normalize-space()
```

which for your document will return,

```
The Example Docx
Introduction
This is the introduction para. Awesome.
Chapter 1
This is the chapter 1 intro para. Awesome.
Chapter 1.1
This is section 1.1 text . Awesome.
Chapter 1.2
This is section 1. 2 text. Awesome.
Chapter 2
This is the c hapter 2 text. Awesome.
```

And that seems tantalizingly close to what you want for nearly no development effort.  You might be able to recover the hierarchy with less effort than the general case if you restrict your input space, but to handle the general case is extremely complex.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a more natural hierarchy in the xml that I can extract easier instead? The forward process after this is relatively open.

Comment: The challenge is that OOXML is format/presentation-oriented, so the hierarchy that might be naturally represented in XML normally as containment is instead encoded in terms of indentation levels and/or style definitions.  If you have total control over the input DOCX, you might restrict your input to simplify your task.  For example, you might impose a convention upon styles and their names.

Answer (score 2):

I took a different approach in the end using `pandoc` - converting to html with `pandoc -s example.docx -o example.html`.  This preserves formatting and links etc and gives much cleaner output to work with.